# how to disable bold font in vim?

Tags: editor, vim

i've removed all references to bold (gui=bold, cterm=bold, term=bold) in the color syntax file slate.vim but i still see some bolded text. for example in a python file, the keywords class, def, try, except, return, etc. are still in a bold blue font.

also how to disable bold in status messages, like "recording" or "Press ENTER or type command.."?

Comment: http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.gvimrc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of removing `=bold` references you should replace them by

```
gui=NONE
cterm=NONE
term=NONE
```

Comment: Not sure why, but that breaks almost everything in macvim for me.

Comment: @AlistairMacDonald Are you sure you just only replaced the `=bold` references by `=NONE` in the [slate.vim](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/msanders/vim-files/master/colors/slate.vim) file?

Comment: No I did it in my `.vimrc` file. I did this in the colors file and this works now. Thanks! You could improve your answer by being a little more explicit about that. That would make your answer an upvote for me.

Comment: Downvote because 90% of `vim` commands mentioned go in the `.vimrc` file and this doesn't, but you make no mention of that.

Comment: @dwanderson just FYI these are parameters of the [highlight](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) command as it is implied by the question.

Answer (score 8):

Put the following line in the .vimrc file.

```
set t_md=
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. Works withou breaking anything else.

Comment: Doesn't work in gVim on Windows for me. Just saying.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone is using iTerm on MacOS and also has this problem (since the same color scheme and vimrc settings under Ubuntu never gave me this problem), there is an option in iTerm under Preference->Profiles->text that stops iTerm from rendering any bold text. That's an easier and quicker fix.

Answer (score 3):

try also to remove the occurrences of `standout`.

You can find highlighting groups by doing the following:

```
:sp $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim | source %
```

You can find where colors and font options were defined by doing:

```
:verbose highlight ModeMsg
```

(replace `ModeMsg` by your highlight group)

Answer (score 1):

In vim, `:scriptnames` shows a list of all scripts loaded at vim startup.

In bash, `grep -rl "=bold" $VIM` shows a list of all files in your vim folder that contain that string. If `$VIM` is not set, or if you have a space in the filename (windows users), `cd` to your vim directory and run the command with `.` in place of `$VIM`

You can compare the two lists to find the files that need editing. Replace `=bold` with `=NONE` as stated in the previous answer by Tassos.

A side note: `:hi` Shows all current highlight formatting, with examples to demonstrate how the syntax is actually being rendered. In my case, `standout` had no effect on whether the font appeared bold.

**Here's the easiest method:**

1. In `/colors` directory enter `sed -i 's/=bold/=NONE/g' *.vim`
2. In `/syntax` directory enter `sed -i 's/=bold/=NONE/g' *.vim`

This will replace every instance in all those *.vim files.

Comment: Bold was a problem for me in Windows. Since switching to Ubuntu, bold is beautiful in vim and gvim. (In Ubuntu, it seems that fonts look better on all applications.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a tmux/screen issue.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237530/tmux-causing-bold-fonts-in-vim led me to `TERM=screen-256color` which resolved my problem. It might also be worth exploring the difference when TERM is `xterm` vs. `xterm-256color`.

Answer (score 0):

@devskii 's [answer in the comment, above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971581/how-to-disable-bold-font-in-vim#comment4277318_3971581), works great for me. I'm going to include specifically the unbolding part here & wiki the answer. (If @devskii would like to make it an answer, I'll delete this... if I can delete wiki answers.)

---

Put this in your `.gvimrc` and smoke it:

```
" Steve Hall wrote this function for me on vim@vim.org
" See :help attr-list for possible attrs to pass
function! Highlight_remove_attr(attr)
    " save selection registers
    new
    silent! put

    " get current highlight configuration
    redir @x
    silent! highlight
    redir END
    " open temp buffer
    new
    " paste in
    silent! put x

    " convert to vim syntax (from Mkcolorscheme.vim,
    "   http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=85)
    " delete empty,"links" and "cleared" lines
    silent! g/^$\| links \| cleared/d
    " join any lines wrapped by the highlight command output
    silent! %s/\n \+/ /
    " remove the xxx's
    silent! %s/ xxx / /
    " add highlight commands
    silent! %s/^/highlight /
    " protect spaces in some font names
    silent! %s/font=\(.*\)/font='\1'/

    " substitute bold with "NONE"
    execute 'silent! %s/' . a:attr . '\([\w,]*\)/NONE\1/geI'
    " yank entire buffer
    normal ggVG
    " copy
    silent! normal "xy
    " run
    execute @x

    " remove temp buffer
    bwipeout!

    " restore selection registers
    silent! normal ggVGy
    bwipeout!
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * call Highlight_remove_attr("bold")
```